# Converting string to utf8-bytes

Tags: java, url-encoding

There's a website I'm trying to scrape that uses some special encoder for its query string. Special characters are encoded to the "UTF-8 Bytes" values seen in the rightmost column of the table on this site http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html. Is there some way I can replicate this on my own in Java, e.g. turn "æ" into "%C3 %A6"?

Comment: Try "ae".getBytes("UTF-8");

Comment: And how do I then turn the byte array into the "%C3 %A6"?

Answer (score -1):

Convert from String to byte[]:

```
String strInput = "Apple";
byte[] utf8ByteOutput = strInput.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Convert from byte[] to String:

```
byte[] utf8ByteInput = {(byte)65, (byte)112, (byte)112, (byte)108, (byte)101};
String strOutput = new String(utf8ByteInput, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: bytes = "æ".getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8")); Yields "?", not "%C3 %A6"...